# ORACLE - Count specific value from whole table (all columns)

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, count

I've got a table named "F_ParqueInfra", that I'd like to count all values in it where the value is equal to -1.

So, this table has 11 columns and 833 rows = 9.163 number of data in this table.

I'd like to know, how many "-1" values has in the whole table (all columns), in the simplest way.
Also I'll do that with a lot of tables in my Data Warehouse.

[image: F_ParqueInfra]

Really thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use dynamic SQL. For example:

```
SQL> select * from f_parqueinfra;

ID_USUARIO ID_EMPRESA ID_DEPARTAMENTO
---------- ---------- ---------------
       250         32              12
        -1         -1              -1
         0         -1               1
         5          2              -1

SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> declare
  2    l_table_name varchar2(30) := 'F_PARQUEINFRA';
  3    l_value number := -1;  -- search value
  4    l_str varchar2(200);   -- to compose SELECT statement
  5    l_cnt number := 0;     -- number of values in one column
  6    l_sum number := 0;     -- total sum of values
  7  begin
  8    for cur_r in (select table_name, column_name
  9                  from user_tab_columns
 10                  where table_name = l_table_name
 11                    and data_type = 'NUMBER'
 12                 )
 13    loop
 14      l_str := 'select count(*) from ' ||cur_r.table_name ||
 15               ' where ' || cur_r.column_name || ' = ' || l_value;
 16      execute immediate l_str into l_cnt;
 17      l_sum := l_sum + l_cnt;
 18    end loop;
 19    dbms_output.put_line('Number of ' || l_value ||' values = ' || l_sum);
 20  end;
 21  /
Number of -1 values = 5

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

If you change `l_value` (line #3), you can search for some other value, e.g.

```
SQL> l3
  3*   l_value number := -1;  -- search value
SQL> c/-1/250
  3*   l_value number := 250;  -- search value
SQL> /
Number of 250 values = 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Or, you can change table name (line #2) and search some other table.

Basically, you'd probably want to turn that anonymous PL/SQL code into a function which would accept table name and search value and return number of appearances. That shouldn't be too difficult so I'll leave it to you, for practice.

---

**[EDIT: converting it into a function]**

Although far from being *perfect*, something like this will let you search for some numeric and string values in tables in current schema. Dates are more complex, depending on formats etc. but - for simple cases - this code *might* be OK for you. Have a look:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_cnt (par_table_name in varchar2,
  2                                    par_data_type  in varchar2,
  3                                    par_value      in varchar2)
  4    return sys.odcivarchar2list
  5  is
  6    l_data_type varchar2(20) := upper(par_data_type);
  7    l_retval    sys.odcivarchar2list := sys.odcivarchar2list();
  8    l_str varchar2(200);   -- to compose SELECT statement
  9    l_out varchar2(200);   -- return value
 10    l_cnt number := 0;     -- number of values in one column
 11    l_sum number := 0;     -- total sum of values
 12  begin
 13    -- loop through all tables in current schema
 14    for cur_t in (select table_name
 15                  from user_tables
 16                  where table_name = upper(par_table_name)
 17                     or par_table_name is null
 18                 )
 19    loop
 20      -- reset the counter
 21      l_sum := 0;
 22      -- loop through all columns in that table
 23      for cur_c in (select column_name
 24                    from user_tab_columns
 25                    where table_name = cur_t.table_name
 26                      and data_type = l_data_type
 27                   )
 28      loop
 29        -- pay attention to search value's data type
 30        if l_data_type = 'VARCHAR2' then
 31           l_str := 'select count(*) from ' ||cur_t.table_name ||
 32                    ' where ' || cur_c.column_name || ' = ' ||
 33                    chr(39) || par_value ||chr(39);
 34        elsif l_data_type = 'NUMBER' then
 35           l_str := 'select count(*) from ' ||cur_t.table_name ||
 36                    ' where ' || cur_c.column_name || ' = ' || par_value;
 37        end if;
 38
 39        execute immediate l_str into l_cnt;
 40        l_sum := l_sum + l_cnt;
 41      end loop;
 42
 43      if l_sum > 0 then
 44         l_out := cur_t.table_name ||' has ' || l_sum ||' search values';
 45         l_retval.extend;
 46         l_retval(l_retval.count) := l_out;
 47      end if;
 48    end loop;
 49    return l_retval;
 50  end;
 51  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select * From table(f_cnt(null, 'number', -1));

COLUMN_VALUE
-----------------------------------------------------------------
F_PARQUEINFRA has 5 search values

SQL> select * From table(f_cnt(null, 'varchar2', 'KING'));

COLUMN_VALUE
-----------------------------------------------------------------
EMP has 1 search values

SQL>
```

Comment: Great solution! How can I execute this on specific owner? Also the solution from @GMB solved as well.

Comment: One option is to connect as "specific owner" and run code in its schema. Another one is to connect as a privileged user (such as SYS), select from DBA_TAB_COLUMNS and include the OWNER column.

Comment: Well, I'm still get some difficulties from convert into a function. How would I use a function to find all those counts from all tables? Where "l_table_name" is equal to all my table from owner (already have this select statment, but I couln'd solved).

Comment: I edited my answer and added some more info & code. Have a look.

Comment: really thanks for your effort for make it work. I never used this function like this before, I always use my functions in "SELECT F_CNT(*)" for example.
I also would like to improve this function, I tried by myself but it's too hard for my skill yet. I'm saving this functions on Data Stage database, but I'd like to execute on my Data Warehouse. I changed the select statement "user_tables" and "user_tab_columns" for "all", but it didn't work. How can we do that? Also, search all lines on the table where field "LINORIGEM" is different from "CARGA MANUAL".

Comment: I'd like to add this select in an another select. Where I get the most important data from the table from the Data Warehouse data base. How can I do? 
I'm trying to change "F_PARQUEINFRA has 1 search values" to "1" only. Because I'll add as a column in my select statement.

Comment: How can I convert "cur_t.table_name " and "l_sum" into columns? Instead of only one column with "l_sum" only.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a good place to use the `unpivot` syntax. This still requires you to type all the column names once - but not more.

Here is an example for 4 columns:

```
select count(*) cnt
from mytable
unpivot(myval for mycol in (col1, col2, col3, col4))
where myval = -1
```

As a bonus, you can easily modify the query to get the number of `-1` per column:

```
select mycol, count(*) cnt
from mytable
unpivot(myval for mycol in (col1, col2, col3, col4))
where myval = -1
group by mycol
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution helped me a lot! I'm still testing @Littlefoot solutions as well.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you need.

**Notes**:

1. performs true numeric comparison (for example would match -1.00 also) using an inline function to prevent error should the value in a compared cell be non-numeric. (if all your compared values are guaranteed to be numeric the inline function can be simplified dramatically)
2. searches only varchar2 and number column types (this can be changed if desired).

The code follows:

```
set serveroutput on size 10000
declare
  vMyTableName   varchar2(200)   := 'F_ParqueInfra';
  vMyValue       number          := -1;
  vSQL           varchar2(4000);
  vTotal         pls_integer;
  vGrandTotal    number(18)    := 0;
  cursor c1 is
    select * 
    from user_tab_columns
    where table_name = vMyTableName;
  vInlineFn varchar2(4000) := 'with
  function matchesMyValue(value varchar2) return pls_integer
           is
  begin
  return case
           when to_number(value) = '||vMyValue||' then
             1
           else 
             0
         end;
exception
  when value_error then
    return 0;
end;
';
begin
  for x in c1 loop
    if x.data_type in ('VARCHAR2','NUMBER') then  -- only looking in these column data types for -1 but you can flex this to suit your column type definitions
      vSQL := 'select sum(matchesMyValue('||x.column_name||')) from '||vMyTableName;
      execute immediate vInlineFn||vSQL into vTotal;
      vGrandTotal := vGrandTotal + vTotal;
    end if;
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line('Total cells containing -1 = '||vGrandTotal);
end;
/
```